# How can I send objects between two states in AngularJS without using rootScope or URL parameters?

Tags: angularjs

When I navigate between one state to another, I want to pass an object to be used in the new state. How can I do this without using global object solutions such as `$rootScope`? Also I don't want to use the state url parameters.

Basically, I want to do  `$state.go('myState', {some: 'thing'})` and inside the controller for "myState" I want to be able to reach the passed object somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "two states" you mean two different controllers, each of them accessible through different routes.

Angular would recommend to use a service for that as the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) says :

> Angular services are substitutable objects that are wired together
>   using dependency injection (DI). You can use services to organize and
>   share code across your app.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean between states? If you mean between controllers, then you could use a shared service to hold the data. Services are singletons, so live for the lifetime of the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can access state parameters in your

```
.controller('ctrl',['$scope','$stateParams',function($scope , $stateParams ) {    

          $scope.getParams = function() {
              console.log( $stateParams.some ); 
          }

    }
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service